# Filtering and sum data in lodash by two keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I working on application which contains lodash and react-select.
I first need filtered data by label. If I have more than one object I need to merge all data in one object but/or if channel key contains any letter from input I need to merge all objects with that type **type**.

Here is problem lodash,  I am using this library for the first time

my array

```
data = [
{label: 'Daily News',
type: 'News',
cost: '3000'}
{label: 'Time News',
type: 'News',
cost: '5000'},
{label: 'Daily News',
type: 'Sport',
cost: '4000'}
]
```

I expeted:

If I typing = 'ew'

I will get a new array for react-search which contains:

```
label: 'Daily News',
value: 'daily-news',
type: 'News',
cost: '7000'
},
{
label: 'News',
value: 'news',
type: 'New',
cost: '8000'
}]
```

Comment: In your data you don't have any element with label `News`, how it appears in output ?

Comment: sounds like you need an autocomplete component then you can do what you need in the `filter` function. In order to sum up identical results you would need a custom filter function.

Comment: @michale yes u right...can you help me

Comment: how do want to merge it ? you just want to add the cost for things that have same labels ? what happens to type attribute ?

Comment: @GoranR is this https://repl.it/repls/AdventurousDramaticQbasic what you are looking for ?

Comment: user93 I need something like that:
 ``` { {label:'Daily News', cost:7000}, {label: 'Time News',  cost: 5000}, {label: 'News', cost: 12000} }```

Comment: @user93 also i need object with type data
 { {label:'Daily News', cost:7000}, {label: 'Time News', cost: 5000}, {label: 'News', cost: 12000} }`

Comment: Have you solved that problem?

Comment: @Mat.Now not yet

Comment: @GoranR the answer below isn't right for you?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved your problem, but in pure JavaScript, because haven't used lodash recently. I hope you will be able to adjust this code to your requirements.

```
let filtered = function(search){
  return data.reduce((acc,item,index)=>{
    if(item.label.includes(search)){
            if(acc.some(e=>e.label === item.label)){
            acc.find(ele=>ele.label === item.label).cost+= Number.parseInt(item.cost)
        return acc
    } else {
         return [...acc,{
            label: item.label,
          cost: Number.parseInt(item.cost)
      }]
    }
  }
  return acc
 },[]).reduce((acc, item)=>{
  if(item){
    if(item.label.includes('News') && acc.some(e=>e.label==='News')){
      acc.find(ele=>ele.label === 'News').cost+= Number.parseInt(item.cost);
      return [...acc, item]
    } else {
      return [...acc, item, {
        label: 'News',
        cost: item.cost
      }]
    }  
  } 
  return acc
  },[])
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4uatqkdh/2/